# Function  for textarea empty

Tags: javascript, chat

Is there a way to implement in chat "the other user is not typing" when  his textarea is empty and "the other user is typing" when the textarea has at least one character?

First, I wanted to implement this "is typing" function by checking every 2 seconds if the user is pressing keys but i've realized it would slow the chat too too much. Is it a simple way to pull the info when the textarea is not empty (user is typing) and when empty- do nothing.

Thank you.

Comment: Use a `keydown` handler. If the user populates the text-box with characters, send the "is typing" message, and if the user empties the text-box, send an empty message (to clear the message output).

Comment: Thank you, I will try to see if I can create the code for  this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the "is typing" message on first `keyup` and use `window.setTimeout` to send the "not typing" message after 10 seconds or so. Cancel and reschedule the setTimeout on every keyup.

Untested example below:

```
var input = document.getElementById('typeeBox');
var isTyping = false;
var timeoutId = 0;

function stoppedTyping() {
    isTyping = false;
    // Send not typing message.
    // Update db status.
}

function startedTyping() {
    if (!isTyping) {
        // Send is typing message.
        // Update db status.
        isTyping = true;
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(stoppedTyping, 10000);
    } else {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(stoppedTyping, 10000);
    }
}

input.addEventListener('keyup', startedTyping, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to test this code right now. Just a quick question, does the time out affect the timer I already have in the chat? I will try the code without it for the moment , just in case.

Comment: The `setTimeout` should simply schedule another function to run, in addition to what you are already running. Likewise, `clearTimeout` will only clear the function to run by the `timeoutId` passed to it.

Comment: Worked, thanks a million. May I ask you just one more thing. I created 2 columns in database one for "member typing status" and the other for "operator typing status" and assigned 0. Now I am a little lost where should I indicate in your code the database request to get the other user's status and not mine.

Comment: Updated code to indicate where you would update the DB. As far as which field, I would imagine that your authentication would determine if was `operator` or `member`.